# Overwinter chillies

Tags: chili, overwintering

Are my chillies dead or will they come back in the summer??[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most chiles are tender perennials and typically do not survive after exposure to freezing temperatures. They can be successfully overwintered indoors or in a greenhouse. It is unlikely that your chiles will come back next year.

The ones with brown stems are definitely gone. The ones with green remaining may have some life left in them, but you'll have more success starting fresh from seed.

Comment: Thank you very much